# PHP Array JSON encoding and decoding in REST not working

Tags: php, arrays, json, rest, decoding

I have the following problem. This data in this structure

```
$transfer = {stdClass} [4]
    module = "Member"
    action = "create"
    token = null
    params = {stdClass} [3]
        username = "Test"
        email = "test@test.com"
        password = "Test"
```

has to be send vi REST to the REST Server.

Therefore I encode the data with json_encode ($object). 
The decoded object looks like this:

```
{"module":"Member","action":"create","token":null,"params":{"username":"Test","email":"test@test.com","password":"Test"}}
```

For testing purpose I decode the encoded result to see if everything works fine. Which gives me the object correct back.

When I transfer the data via curl, the server receives this json_encoded data:

```
{"module":"Member","action":"create","token":null,"params":{"username":"Test","email":"test@test.com" = ""
```

And finally the json_decode($request) ands up with the following error:

```
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

The curl code for this is:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);

// prepare curl for Basic Authentication
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

$curl_post_data = json_encode($postdata);
$test = json_decode($curl_post_data); // for testing

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data); <= $postdata = $transfer the object/array mentioned above
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

What's wrong? Why it is not possible to decode the encoded data after the curl exec to the REST Server?

Comment: Please check Code :- 
$object = '[{"module":"Member","action":"create","token":null,"params":{"username":"Test","email":"test@test.com","password":"Test"}}]';
$data = json_decode($object);
string problem

Comment: What do you mean with check code Sunny? I putted also the curl statement in addition now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the magic solution for that problem:

```
json_decode(key($object), true);
```

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding you are sending $curl_post_data which is a json_encoded string in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` accepts array not a string.

So you should pass `$curl_post_data['data'] = json_encode($postdata);`

and receive data `json_decode($request['data'])`

You are facing error(json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given) because $request is blank as you passed the string

Comment: Minus rating is not from me. I don't know why this happend, there is no comment. Please stay tuned to this topic.

Comment: i want to answer question that's why i asked for curl data.And i answered it in edit.I can't comment because i am new here that's why i asked in answer

Comment: @DewanshuSharma you should answer some different questions that don't require you to misuse the answer field till you get the rep to comment.

Comment: $curl_post_data['data'] is not working, the rest call won't be fired with that.

Comment: you can pass either array or url_encoded string like this 'data='.urlencode(json_encode($postdata)) and now you can get $postdata by $request['data']                 or  add this curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postdata)));